# Excel interop adds @ sign to formulas

Tags: excel-interop

when creating a spreadsheet using Excel interop's and VB.NET I need to add a formula to a cell.

for example the filter formula. I add it as =Filter but when it appears on the spreadsheet it appears as =@Filter

this means that only the cell that I added the formula to will bring back the data in the filter, whereas without the @ it would bring back the array in the corresponding cells.

is there a way of stopping the @ symbol appearing?

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: The disadvantage of structured references is that there is no $ sign to make references absolute. Instead there is the @ sign, for much the same purposes. But since structured references are supposed to be easier to use than legacy ones you don't get to choose. The effect is that, if the structured reference doesn't do what you want, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response.
if i add the function directly intoan Excel cell wihtout the @ symbol it does as i want it to.
its only when i try to add the function via Interop that it puts the @ symbol in.Is there no way of stopping this?

Comment: Apparently not. Work around it. Use another method of referencing the columns.

Comment: i have tried to do a find and replace on the formula using
 wSheet3.Range("C5").Replace(What:="@", Replacement:="", LookAt:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, SearchOrder:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2)

this works in VBA but using the interop i dont know how to reference xlReplaceFormula2 (i.e. for xlPart i had to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart)

Comment: sorted it. Instead of having wSheet3.Range("C5").Formula = "=FILTER.etc" i just need to use wSheet3.Range("C5").Formula2 = "=FILTER.etc
.

Answer (score 1):

Use wSheet3.Range("C5").Formula2 = and then the formula instead of
wSheet3.Range("C5").Formula =

Comment: This should be selected as the solution. Thank you!